# Как сделать закругление во внутрь на таком макете?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] есть такая картинка как сделать эти 2 блока через цсс и html основная проблема в закругляшке слева

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Покажите разметку html и текущие стили

Comment: нет разметки, в этом и дело что я учусь и в процессе есть такой вот блок интересует как сделать закругление с левой стороны у правого блока это все что я хочу узнать я не прошу решить задачу , а только сказать как можно делать закругления во внутрь блока

Comment: сделай закругление наружу у левого блока. простой круг с оверфлоу хиден

Comment: @eri, не совсем - на радиус обрати внимание.

Comment: обычный радиус, ничего такого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 1fr;
  gap: 3em;
  background: antiquewhite;
}

main::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  clip-path: circle(100% at 0 50%);
}

section {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h1>Тут контент</h1>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть разные способы такого скругления. Например вот такой, искусственный:

```css
#rel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

#abs1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  background: orange;
}

#abs2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: beige;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="rel">
  <div id="abs1"></div>
  <div id="abs2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это не совсем похоже на макет. Есть пара улучшений: в boprder-radius вместо 100px можно написать 100vmax чтобы получить круг, не зависящий от размеров блока. Ещё можно написать `50vmax 100vmax` и получится эллипс. Но в вопросе явно дуга большего радиуса - кажется, через border-radius такое не очень удобно делать.